# PHP parse Error while executing a lengthy regex shell command from within php

Tags: php, regex, shell, awk, sed

when i try parsing a file by executing this command from within php using shell_exec():

```
$shellCommand = "cat $filelocn | awk 'BEGIN{RS="<br>"}{$1=$1}1' |sed '/CURRENT/d' ";
echo $shellCommand ;
```

An error is displayed:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '>' in filename.php
```

> i also tried adding \ before ' ie: `"cat $filelocn | awk \'BEGIN{RS=\"<br>\"}{$1=$1}1'";`
>   but it again throws error.

How do i resolve this issue ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: Thank you @Dekel , i looked into it ; but how do i resolve regex parse error

Comment: It's not regex parse error. it's simply php parse errors.

Comment: Case your code would be `echo " abc " def ";` you get the exact same error.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're trying to interpolate variables in your PHP code into your string, you need to escape the dollar signs too:

```
$shellCommand = "cat \$filelocn | awk 'BEGIN{RS=\"<br>\"}{\$1=\$1}1' |sed '/CURRENT/d' ";
echo $shellCommand;
```

Specifically, the `$1`s are causing your parse error. If `$filelocn` is a PHP variable, you don't need to escape it.